# React Router How to have parent routes and sub routes with paramters

Tags: react-router

I have 2 routes:

```
<Route path="/hello/:name" component={A}> 
<Route path="/hello/custom/:name" component={B}>
```

Now when I navigate to /hello/custom/aPerson. Component A and B are called. How can I avoid that? Currently I have to add logic to component A to check its param :name to see if any "/" is used. If so, I disable component A.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to add `exact` to the routes.

```
<Route exact path="/hello/:name" component={A}> 
<Route exact path="/hello/custom/:name" component={B}>
```